# VPN Masquerade and NAT

Tags: port-forwarding, iptables, openvpn

I'm trying to set up a VPS to forward traffic from a openvpn client to the internet, while forwarding incoming port 80 traffic back to the client. I've followed [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-debian-8) to configure the server and create a client config. On the VPS I have the iptables rules:

```
-t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/8 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

and

```
-t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.6
```

The first rule is from the guide, and works well. The second rule allows me to connect to the VPN client on port 80 from the internet, but http requests from the client to the internet fail (https stills works, and goes through the VPN). Can anyone recommend a working configuration for this problem, or explain why this one doesn't work?

Edit: VPS configuration

```
# iptables -L -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source        destination  

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source        destination  

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source        destination  

# iptables -L -n -t nat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source        destination  
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0     0.0.0.0/0    tcp dpt:80 to:10.8.0.6

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source        destination  

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source        destination  

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source        destination  
MASQUERADE  all  --  10.0.0.0/8    0.0.0.0/0   

# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1
```

Comment: I guess the linux on which you are executing this rules is the gateway to internet, right? first route is ok because you are behind NAT. And with the second one if I didn't understood in a bad way... you want to reach your internal server from internet, is correct that? anyway we need to know all your iptables rules... use `iptables -L` and ìptables -t nat -L` to show them... is the FORWARD chain with ACCEPT policy?

Comment: Yes, the VPS is the gateway. I edited my post to show it's config.

Comment: I saw you edited post... nice. We need more data... what do you have if you execute `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` a 0 or a 1 ? because I think you need a 1 here.

Comment: What ports are needed to connect to openvpn from a internet client? only 80 tcp? I saw in the manual you put on the link, they use udp 1194. The mapping seems correct for 80 tcp port. Be sure of that openvpn host has the right gateway (the linux with the iptables machine)

Comment: I have opevpn set up to connect on udp 1194. http wget's initiated from the vpn client don't connect to the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prerouting rule didn't specify an interface or destination, so http requests coming from the VPN client over tun0 were being sent back to itself.

A working config is

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/8 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i eth0 -d $eth0_addr --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 10.8.0.6
```

Comment: nice! so you can mark your own answer as resolved. I hope any of my comments helped you. Cheers!